# java mongodb-driver-reactivestreams is not working but mongo-java-driver works

Tags: java, mongodb

I am facing an issue in using async mongo functionality in my java code.
(Running MongoDB 4.2.15 Community in local machine in standalone mode)

I tested mongo java driver (sync) which works fine , able to insert doc to db.
(Below is code)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase(databaseName);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
Document doc = new Document()
                    .append("Timestamp", new Date(iLoggingEvent.getTimeStamp()))
                    .append("Ip", "hostIp");

collection.insertOne(doc);


Logs when I use "mongo-java-driver" jar :

10:28:12.293 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
10:28:12.312 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
10:28:12.328 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
10:28:12.329 [cluster-ClusterId{value='611de4e4e96a2b213cf32576', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:470}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
10:28:12.329 [cluster-ClusterId{value='611de4e4e96a2b213cf32576', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Checking status of 127.0.0.1:27017
10:28:12.330 [cluster-ClusterId{value='611de4e4e96a2b213cf32576', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 15]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=390200}
10:28:12.331 [cluster-ClusterId{value='611de4e4e96a2b213cf32576', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=0.4 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
10:28:12.335 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:471}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
10:28:12.342 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Inserting 1 documents into namespace mydb.mycoll on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:471}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
10:28:12.347 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Insert completed
```

But when I tried to use 'mongodb-driver-async' or 'mongodb-driver-reactivestreams' jars for async, even though code executes without any error it is not inserting the document to DB.

Below is the code I am trying :
(Simple and advanced connection both the options I tried, and did not work)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
      </dependency>


MongoClient mongoClient1 = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient1.getDatabase("nifi");
        Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
                .append("type", "database")
                .append("count", 1)
                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));
        Publisher<Success> publisher = database.getCollection("log").insertOne(doc);

        publisher.subscribe(new Subscriber<Success>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
                s.request(1);  // <--- Data requested and the insertion will now occur
                System.out.println("Its calling this");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final Success success) {
                System.out.println("onNext");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("onError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("onComplete");
            }
        });




## OR

List<ServerAddress> serverList = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        serverList.add(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));
        ClusterSettings clusterSettings = ClusterSettings.builder().hosts(serverList).build();
        ConnectionPoolSettings poolSettings = ConnectionPoolSettings.builder()
                .minSize(1)
                .maxSize(4)
                .build();

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                    .applyToClusterSettings(builder1 -> builder1.applySettings(clusterSettings))
                    .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder1 -> builder1.applySettings(poolSettings))
                    .build();
        
        
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
        MongoDatabase  database = client.getDatabase("nifi");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("log");
        
        Document doc = new Document()
                .append("Timestamp", new Date(iLoggingEvent.getTimeStamp()))
                .append("Server", "Nifi");
        collection.insertOne(doc);



Log when I use "mongodb-driver-reactivestreams" :

10:48:31.435 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
10:48:31.460 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
10:48:31.510 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by com.mongodb.internal.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$1@167fdd33 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated !

Thanks
Mahendra

Answer (score 0):

Main process (method) was exiting before even async functions executes..
So just added Thread.sleep(1000); after connection code and it worked..

Thing is, for async function to work in background, main process should not exit..